Is there a technical reason ViewBindings doesn't also give you a programmatic inflater?
It seems on each Android release, the layout inflater is getting slower. In many cases, the speed slowdown is 4x between Lollipop and Upside Down Cake. The solution people point to is to programmatically generate views. However, if ViewBindings is already parsing the XML file and generating code, is there a technical reason why it couldn't also generate the view itself programmatically? This seems like something that would be obvious to speed up almost everyone's code while simultaneously encouraging good style and more correct programs.
For instance, if you do, ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflator()) it will, at least as far as I'm aware, go through the standard process of loading the XML files that would happen with inflater.inflate(R.id.activity_main), it just also does the findViewById for you.  However, since it is doing code generation for that anyway, is there a reason why it couldn't also do code generation for inflating from XML?  At minimum, this would bypass all filesystem calls and XML parsing which could lead to massive speed boosts at no cost.
In any case, I didn't know if there was a technical reason this hasn't been done or if it just hasn't been on anyone's radar?  Or is it available and I just don't know about it?

They'd started to do something like that right before Compose happened, and then it kinda just disappeared. The thing is, IIRC, it was called "Composed Views" or "Pre-composed" or something like that, so it's nigh impossible to search for it without getting overwhelmed with results for the new framework. Surely someone else remembers better than I do. I seem to recall that it was in the androidx repo somewhere, but it may have been removed by now.

"this would bypass all filesystem calls" -- no, it would move them to be when the app starts and the Dalvik/ART bytecode for the generated code gets loaded.

Looks like they were called simply "compiled" or "precompiled", though I thought that they'd intentionally avoided that name, for some reason. In any case, it seems that they weren't seeing justifiable benefits from that approach: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/72fd8769f97305b1fb1b3d16b3f4215f6035a25a.

Here's one reason why it's problematic to generate code (at build time) that inflates layouts:
Resources are provided at runtime depending on the specific device configuration. You can have alternative XML files for cases like:

portrait orientation / landscape orientation
right-to-left direction / left-to-right direction
day time / night time
different languages
different screen shapes

Besides, resources can reference other resources.
And generating code for all the possible combinations of form factors is impractical.
